# Structure as init argument in a mex file

Tags: c++, c, matlab, simulink, mex

I have a mask in simulink that has an init argument field. The init argument in my case is a structure. Now I want to use this structure in the .ccp (to make a mex file).

```
void init()
{
    mxArray *initarg = GetInitArg();
    ...
}
```

The `GetInitArg()` is :

```
#ifndef GET_INIT_ARG
#define GET_INIT_ARG

mxArray *GetInitArg() {

  return rtsys->initArg;

}

#endif
```

When the initarg is an `int`, I can call it this way in the `void init()`:

```
int arg = (int)mxGetPr(initarg)[0];
```

Now, how would I do if initarg is a Matlab structure?

**EDIT**

I tried using @remus answer.

My struct look like this :

```
typedef struct
{
    const char *task;
    aaa_type aaa;
    bbb_type bbb;
    ccc_type ccc;
} arg_t;
```

The struct `aaa_type`, `bbb_type` and `ccc_type` are defined like this :

```
typedef struct
{
    double p1;
    double p2;
    double p3;
    double p4;
    double p5;
    double p6;
} aaa_type;
```

I try to get the init arg like this :

```
void init() 
{
    mxArray *initarg = GetInitArg();
    arg_t arg* = (arg_t*)mxGetPr(initarg);
    ...
}
```

But at the arg_t line i'm getting two compilation errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' 
error C2059: syntax error : '='
```

Comment: Your arg_t is a C structure, not a MATLAB structure, so this is the right approach.  It looks like you simply haven't included the definition of arg_t in your MEX file.

Comment: arg_t arg* should be arg_t* arg; hence the syntax error.

Comment: But the approach doesn't work with strings. A matlab structure doesn't save a string as a char*...

Comment: So why do you say your struct "looks like this", indicating a C structure with a char * member, if that's not what you have?  Where did the definition for the arg_t struct come from?  Are you trying to convert to the arg_t struct from the equivalent MATLAB struct?  It's starting to sound like you're back to my answer, where you need to pick apart the MATLAB struct using MEX calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of MEX functions related to accessing structures is below:

```
mxGetField
mxSetField
mxGetNumberOfFields
mxGetFieldNameByNumber
mxGetFieldNumber
mxGetFieldByNumber
mxSetFieldByNumber
```

If you have a 1x1 structure, here's how you'd get one of the values:

```
mxArray *field_name = mxGetField(initArg, 0, "field_name");
```

Note that the result is another mxArray.  From there you want the usual `mxGetPr()` for double arrays, or other `mxGet...` for other datatypes.

See the MEX documentation section on C/C++ Matrix Library for API details on these functions: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cc-mx-matrix-library.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have the structure definition then you could cast the parameter pointer to it (I haven't tested but it should work since the Matlab structure is a contiguous memory block). Let's say you define your structure somewhere in a .h file:

```
typedef struct {
 double a;
 double b;
} mystruct_t;
```

Then:

```
mystruct_t *arg = (mystruct_t*)mxGetPr(initarg);
```

And you can access its members:

```
if (arg->a == 1) // or whatever
```

Comment: Nice solution. Now, what if my Matlab structure is containing other structures?

Comment: Should work. I have structures of structures and work fine in my C S functions.

Comment: Use this answer if your input is a C structure.  Use my answer if your input is a MATLAB structure, which has a different memory layout than a C structure.

Comment: My input is a Matlab structure. Actually, when I use @remus answer, i get some error. See the edit to my question.